# Decomposing change over time and choice of reference period

Tags: time-series, decomposition

Suppose you observe an aggregate outcome at time 1 that is made up of $k$ components:
$$Y_1=w^1_1 \cdot y^1_1+w^1_2 \cdot y^1_2+...+w^1_k \cdot y^1_k=w^1y^1.$$
You can think of $w$ vector as a set of $k$ mix weights that vary with time and might be estimated from data. Similarly, to fix the idea, $y_k$ are observable quantities. Similarly, the outcome at time 0 is
$$Y_0=w^0_1 \cdot y^0_1+w^0_2 \cdot y^0_2+...+w^0_k \cdot y^0_k=w^0y^0.$$

If you add and subtract $w^1y^0$ on the right, you can re-write the change over time as
$$Y_1-Y_0=w^1y^1-w^0y^0+(w^1y^0-w^1y^0)=w^1(y^1-y^0)+(w^1-w^0)y^0.$$

This allows you to decompose the aggregate change into a "structural" change term and a mix-shift term.

But you could just as easily do the same thing with $w^0y^1$ to get
$$Y_1-Y_0=w^1y^1-w^0y^0+(w^0y^1-w^0y^1)=w^0(y^1-y^0)+(w^1-w^0)y^1.$$

Is there any principled way to choose which one to use? Or is it completely arbitrary? This comes up in the context of Oaxaca-Blinder decomposition in [discrimination literature](https://www.nber.org/papers/w16045.pdf), where there is a debate on whom you should use as a reference group (the discriminated group, the non-discriminated group, or pooled). However, I have not seen the choice of reference period discussed in the time series context.